Available Power Gain Formula
I was going through David Pozar book "Microwave Engineering, 4th Edition" on page 561, Two-ports power gains, i was redoing the calculation for \$ G_A = \frac{P_{avn}}{P_{avs}} \$ i have a problem when working out the expression of \$ P_{avn} \$, here whats written: 
I dont understand whats the algebra taken to find that final result in the RHS for the second equation, since : \$|1- \Gamma_s\Gamma_{in}| =  \frac{(1-\Gamma_s S_{11})(1-\Gamma_{out}^*S_{22})-S_{12}S_{21}\Gamma_s \Gamma_{out}^*}{(1-\Gamma_{out}^* S_{22})}\$, since \$\Gamma_{out}^*=\Gamma_L\$ that means there is no reflection by the load , so which S-params are zero in this case?
PS : \$ \Gamma_{in} = S_{11} + \frac{S_{12}S_{21}\Gamma_s}{1-\Gamma_s S_{11}}\$

\$\Gamma_{out} = S_{22} + \frac{S_{12}S_{21}\Gamma_s}{1-S_{11}\Gamma_s} \iff (\Gamma_{out}-S_{22})(1-S_{11}\Gamma_s) = S_{21}S_{12}\Gamma_s\$
Thus \$|1-\Gamma_s\Gamma_{in} | = |\frac{(1-\Gamma_s S_{11})(1- \Gamma_{out}^*S_{22})-\Gamma_{out}^*(\Gamma_{out}-S_{22})(1-S_{11}\Gamma_s)}{1-S_{22}\Gamma_{out}^*}| =| \frac{(1-\Gamma_s S_{11})(1-|\Gamma_{out}|^2)}{1-\Gamma_{out}^* S_{22}}| \$
